# Counting valid sequences with dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am pretty new to Dynamic Programming, but I am trying to get better. I have an exercise from a book, which asks me the following question (slightly abridged):

You want to construct sequence of length N from numbers from the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. However, you cannot place the number i (i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) more than A[i] times consecutively, where A is a given array. Given the sequence length N (1 <= N <= 10^5) and the constraint array A (1 <= A[i] <= 50), how many sequences are possible?

For instance if A = {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2} and N = 2, this would mean you can only have one consecutive 1, two consecutive 2's, one consecutive 3, etc. Here, something like "11" is invalid since it has two consecutive 1's, whereas something like "12" or "22" are both valid. It turns out that the actual answer for this case is 33 (there are 36 total two-digit sequences, but "11", "33", and "55" are all invalid, which gives 33).

---

Somebody told me that one way to solve this problem is to use dynamic programming with three states. More specifically, they say to keep a 3d array dp(i, j, k) with i representing the current position we are at in the sequence, j representing the element put in position i - 1, and k representing the number of times that this element has been repeated in the block. They also told me that for the transitions, we can put in position i every element different from j, and we can only put j in if A[j] > k.

It all makes sense to me in theory, but I've been struggling with implementing this. I have no clue how to begin with the actual implementation other than initializing the matrix dp. Typically, most of the other exercises had some sort of "base case" that were manually set in the matrix, and then a loop was used to fill in the other entries.

I guess I am particularly confused because this is a 3D array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a moment let's just not care about the array. Let's implement this recursively. Let `dp(i, j, k)` be the number of sequences with length `i`, last element `j`, and `k` consecutive occurrences of `j` at the end of the array.

The question now becomes how do we write the solution of `dp(i, j, k)` recursively.

Well we know that we are adding a `j` the `kth` time, so we have to take each sequence of length `i - 1`, and has `j` occurring `k - 1` times, and add another `j` to that sequence. Notice that this is simply `dp(i - 1, j, k - 1)`.

But what if `k == 1`? If that's the case we can add one occurence of `j` to every sequence of length `i - 1` that doesn't end with `j`. Essentially we need the sum of all `dp(i, x, k)`, such that `A[x] >= k` and `x != j`.

This gives our recurrence relation:

```
def dp(i, j, k):

    # this is the base case, the number of sequences of length 1
    # one if k is valid, otherwise zero
    if i == 1: return int(k == 1)

    if k > 1:
        # get all the valid sequences [0...i-1] and add j to them
        return dp(i - 1, j, k - 1)

    if k == 1:
        # get all valid sequences that don't end with j
        res = 0
        for last in range(len(A)):
            if last == j: continue
            for n_consec in range(1, A[last] + 1):
                res += dp(i - 1, last, n_consec)
        return res
```

We know that our answer will be all valid subsequences of length `N`, so our final answer is `sum(dp(N, j, k) for j in range(len(A)) for k in range(1, A[j] + 1))`

Believe it or not this is the basis of dynamic programming. We just broke our main problem down into a set of subproblems. Of course, right now our time is exponential because of the recursion. We have two ways to lower this:

1. Caching, we can simply keep track of the result of each (i, j, k) and then spit out what we originally computed when it's called again.
2. Use an array. We can reimplement this idea with bottom-up dp, and have an array `dp[i][j][k]`. All of our function calls just become array accesses in a for loop. Note that using this method forces us iterate over the array in topological order which may be tricky.

Comment: Oh, in the solution `len(A) == N`, since the array you give me is gonna be `N` long anyway

Comment: I think `len(A) == N` is not necessarily true. `len(A) = 6` is always true, but then for example, we have N = 2. I am still reading it though. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have been trying to modify the Python code so that `N` is the length of the desired sequence (not necessarily the same as `len(A)`, which is always 6), but I have been struggling to do so. I was wondering whether you would be able to please help me with this. I am pretty sure I can do caching by myself since I have seen many examples of that.

Comment: @joseph omfg, i misinterpreted the question, I thought we were constructing something from {1, 2, 3 ... N}, give me a bit to edit lmao

Comment: Ok, no problem :) Thanks for your help

Comment: @joseph the above should be good, I just had to modify the expression for computing the answer to start from N

Comment: @joseph I have done too much LeetCode for my own good :)) Happy to help :)

Comment: How do you suggest I store the previously computed values in a cache table? I tried doing a 3D array, like `cache[100005][6][100005]`, but I think this takes up too much space.

Comment: @joseph the method I use in the repl uses a hashmap. What language are you using? Does it allow for dynamically determining array sizes?

Comment: I am using C++. I want to do memoization so that it no longer takes exponential time. But the code won't even compile if I'm using that much space.

Comment: @joseph You want to create an array of size `cache[N + 1][6][51]`, since `A[i] <= 50`

Comment: Ohhh ok. I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 kinds of dp approaches: top-down and bottom-up

In bottom up, you fill the terminal cases in dp table and then use for loops to build up from that. Lets consider bottom-up algo to generate Fibonacci sequence. We set `dp[0] = 1` and `dp[1] = 1` and run a for loop from `i = 2 to n`.

In top down approach, we start from the "top" view of the problem and go down from there. Consider the recursive function to get n-th Fibonacci number:

```py
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    if dp[n] != -1:
        return dp[n]
    dp[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    return dp[n]
```

Here we don't fill the complete table, but only the cases we encounter.

Why I am talking about these 2 types is because when you start learning dp, it is often difficult to come up with bottom-up approaches (like you are trying to). When this happens, first you want to come up with a top-down approach, and then try to get a bottom up solution from that.

So let's create a recursive dp function first:

```py
# let m be size of A
# initialize dp table with all values -1
def solve(i, j, k, n, m):
    # first write terminal cases
    if k > A[j]:
        # this means sequence is invalid. so return 0
        return 0
    if i >= n:
        # this means a valid sequence.
        return 1
    if dp[i][j][k] != -1:
        return dp[i][j][k]
    result = 0
    for num = 1 to m:
        if num == j:
            result += solve(i + 1, num, k + 1, n)
        else:
            result += solve(i + 1, num, 1, n)
    dp[i][j][k] = result
    return dp[i][j][k]
```

So we know what terminal cases are. We create a dp table of size dp[n + 1][m][50]. Initialize it with all values 0, not -1.

So we can do bottom-up as:

```py
# initially all values in table are zero. With loop below, we set the valid endings as 1.
# So any state trying to reach valid terminal states will get 1, but invalid states will
# return the values 0
for num = 1 to m:
    for occour = 1 to A[num]:
        dp[n][num][occour] = 1

# now to build up from bottom, we start by filling n-1 th position
for i = n-1 to 1:
    for num = 1 to m:
        for occour = 1 to A[num]:
            for next_num = 1 to m:
                if next_num != num:
                    dp[i][num][occour] += dp[i + 1][next_num][1]
                else:
                    dp[i][num][occour] += dp[i + 1][num][occour + 1]
```

The answer will be:

```
sum = 0
for num = 1 to m:
    sum += dp[1][num][1]
```

I am sure there must be some more elegant dp solution, but I believe this answers your question. Note that I considered that k is the number of times j-th number has been repeated consecutively, correct me if I am wrong with this.

Edit:

With the given constraints the size of the table will be, in the worst case, 10^5 * 6 * 50 = 3e7. This would be > 100MB. It is workable, but can be considered too much space use (I think some kernels doesn't allow that much stack space to a process). One way to reduce it would be to use a **hash-map** instead of an array with top down approach since top-down doesn't visit all the states. That would be mostly true in this case, for example if A[1] is 2, then all the other states where 1 has occoured more that twice need not be stored. Ofcourse this would not save much space if A[i] has large values, say [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]. Another approach would be to modify our approach a bit. We dont actually need to store the dimension k, i.e. the times j has appeared consecutively:

`dp[i][j] = no of ways from i-th position if (i - 1)th position didn't have j and i-th position is j.`

Then, we would need to modify our algo to be like:

```py
def solve(i, j):
    if i == n:
        return 1
    if i > n:
        return 0
    if dp[i][j] != -1
        return dp[i][j]
    result = 0
    # we will first try 1 consecutive j, then 2 consecutive j's then 3 and so on
    for count = 1 to A[j]:
        for num = 1 to m:
            if num != j:
                result += solve(i + count, num)
    dp[i][j] = result
    return dp[i][j]
```

This approach will reduce our space complexity to O(10^6) ~= 2mb, while time complexity is still the same : O(N * 6 * 50)

Comment: Wouldn't it be really difficult to store it in a dp[][][] table? Because N = 10^5, we would take 10^5 * 6 * 10^5 = too much space. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @joseph Sorry, I missed out the part that 1 <= A[i] <= 50. I have updated the answer to reflect this and discussed a better approach.